# QtConcurrent::map segmentation fault

Tags: qt, qtconcurrent

When I have been trying to implement "parallel for" using QtConcurrent::map:

```
QFuture<void> parForAsync(size_t n, std::function<void (size_t)> Op)
{

    size_t nThreads =
            static_cast<size_t>(QThreadPool::globalInstance()->maxThreadCount());
    size_t nn = n/nThreads + 1;

    using Sequence = QVector<std::function<void()>>;
    Sequence vFuns;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i+=nn)
    {
        size_t firstIdx = i,
                lastIdx = i + nn > n ? n : i + nn;

        vFuns.push_back([=]()->void
        {
            for(size_t i = firstIdx; i < lastIdx; ++i)
            {
                Op(i);
            }
        });
    }
    return QtConcurrent::map<Sequence>    //<-Segmentation fault!
            (vFuns, [](std::function<void()> f)
    {
        f();
    });
}
```

I've got segmentation fault in this place:

```
template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
    function(const function& __x)
    : _Function_base()
    {
      if (static_cast<bool>(__x))
    {
      __x._M_manager(_M_functor, __x._M_functor, __clone_functor); //<-Segmentation fault!
      _M_invoker = __x._M_invoker;
      _M_manager = __x._M_manager;
    }
    }
```

Why is this happening? It seems that std::function had passed checking. How can I make this code working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your case but I can give you some example to illustrate issue

```
QFuture<void> test ()
{   
    QVector<int> v; // LOCAL VARIABLE IN SCOPE OF test FUNCTION

    // preparing v vector

    QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::map(v,someFunction); // returns immediately
    return f;
}
```

[1] `QtConcurrent::map` takes `v` by reference NOT BY COPY.

[2] `QtConcurrent::map` returns immediately.

[3] So when `test` function ends, parallel operations started by `map` use `v` vector which was deleted because it is local variable in `test` function.

You can use `waitForFinished` for `QFuture` but then your function doesn't make sense because it blocks until parallel task ends.